# How do I pass data from mysite.com to anothersite.com?

Tags: php, api, request

My client have a website(mysite.com) that I need to pass data(name, price, quantity) of a product into another site(anothersite.com) in order to process the payment. 
Is it possible to do that securely without using woo-commerce API?

For example:

I used the following code, but I can't get the value on another site site $_POST.

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

    $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['data'] );        
    $asAttributes = $product->get_attributes();     

    $data = array(
    'price' => $product->get_price(),
    'desc' => $product->get_description(),
    'qtty' => $cart_item['quantity']
    );
}   

$url = "anothersite.com";

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
return $url;
curl_close($ch);
```

Please note: I can get the data using URL parameters but it is not secured since it is visible in the URL. I need advice on how I can accomplish this securely pleas?

Thank you.

Comment: there is only way is api

Comment: 1. collect data; 2. create a random-named txt file, for ex.; 3. fill this file; 4. move this file in special dir on the another.website; 5. load script with file_get_contents externally from myweb on anotherweb via GET url request; 6. get response with variables from those PHP script

Comment: You can of course POST any data to any site.  If the remote site is set up to accept it, you can receive that data.  `I can't get the value on another site site $_POST` - why not? What happens?

Comment: You still have not given us enough info to be able to help.  You can POST, you can receive that POSTed data.  Edit your question and describe what is happening - be specific, `I can't get the value` does not tell us anything.

Answer (score 0):

I personally cannot see much problem out from this code. Your idea of using CURL is basically correct for most applications.

I have tested your code out on my local server, and I can get the POST paramters without any problem. I'll give you the code I used:

```
<?php
// The page that initiates the CURL request
$data = array(
    'price' => 'A',
    'desc' => 'B',
    'qtty' => 'C'
);   

$url = "https://api.zbx1425.tk:8953/testing/showsuper.php";
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
return $url;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

```
<?php
// The showsuper.php page that receives that
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

And here's the result I got:

```
string(101) "array(3) { ["price"]=> string(1) "A" ["desc"]=> string(1) "B" ["qtty"]=> string(1) "C" } "
```

So I think the problem might be somewhere else. For example you are using for-each for your cart items, but you are overwriting the $data. I don't know about your application so I cannot give a solution, but maybe your page is not sending the data in the correct format.

Comment: Even using your code it keeps giving me " Undefined index". Using isset will post nothing at all. I am not sure why. I will try rewrite it again. Thank you Nemo!